# ESFQ is not control the upload

Tags: linux, tc, qos

I am using IMQ and Iptables to control the packages outcome from my LAN using ESFQ, but it is not work at all.

How I can control the upload of my LAN, I know that others systems like Mikrotik, has its own QoS similar to ESFQ and it can control the upload correctly. There are other alternative to simulate the ESFQ mechanism to control uploads?

Comment: When you say "control the upload" are you talking about throttling the upload speed?

Comment: yes, but note that I want to share my upload bandwidth equally between users, like esfq